# Which Android x86 image from the official site will work for Dell XPS 15?

Tags: installation, android-x86

I want to try to install Android x86 on my XPS 15. However, I don't know which image I should select. Which one would be close to my configuration? Also, is there a custom image I can use as a general build?

I have a 64-bit machine and so have doubts about the stability of the system.

My config :

```
Core        : i5 2nd gen
RAM         : 8GB
GPU         : 1GB nVidia 525M
Peripherals : Trackpad, 2MP VGA camera
```

Please comment if more info is needed.

Comment: There doesn't really look like a good candidate there, given that the Dell one for 4.0 has a UK keyboard.  You could try it though, or `Android-x86 2.2-r2 live & installation iso for Dell Inspiron Mini Duo platform` if you don't mind an old version.

Comment: It has been almost impossible to buy a 32-bit only desktop/laptop CPU for quite a few years now, they're almost all 64-bit (but often run a 32-bit OS). I wouldn't worry about stability from that point of view, it will have been tested on a 64-bit CPU.